# Identify an app by Client Secret or Client Certificate

Tags: c#, azure-keyvault

I have .Net 4.6.1 app that needs to access some secrets from Azure Key Vault and I am doing it in the following manner:

```
        var clientCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
            azureClientData.AzureTenantId,
            azureClientData.AzureClientID,
            azureClientData.AzureClientSecret);

        _client = new SecretClient(keyVaultUri, clientCredential);
```

Azure Portal's App registration mentions that client certificate is a better option than the client secret. I would like to know if I am operating in private cloud , does it really matter (client secret / client certificate) ?

Even if I choose to move to certificate based authentication the code snippet looks as follows:

```
        var clientCerCredential = new ClientCertificateCredential(
            azureClientData.AzureTenantId,
            azureClientData.AzureClientID,
            azureClientData.AzureClientCertificatePath); // Is it the local path to the certificate that is downloaded as CER/PEM format from Azure Key Vault ?



        _client = new CertificateClient(keyVaultUri, clientCredential);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it the local path to the certificate that is downloaded as CER/PEM
> format from Azure Key Vault ?

*"`clientCertificatePath` is the path to a file which contains both the client certificate and private key."* It always is the local path, but if you store it to **OneDrive** the path will format like "C:\Users\myuser\OneDrive - Microsoft\Documents\Certs".

> if I am operating in private cloud, does it really matter (client
> secret / client certificate)?

In short, certificate is more secure than secret but it's complex to use. Which one you choose depends on your requirement. In my opinion, client secret can protect the Azure Key Vault when updating secret every few months.

There are the pros and cons of client secret and client certificate:

> **Client secret:**
>
> Pro: Easy to deploy - just takes some code and a secure data store.
> Depending on the security policy, can autogenerate passwords or force
> new users to create them.
>
> Pro: Easy to administrate - password resets can (for some security
> policies) be done with automated tools
>
> Con: For good security, passwords should be reset early and often.
> User's forgetting or failing to change passwords is either a security
> risk or a usability hassle.
>
> Con: Good passwords can be hard to remember, which leads to the issues
> of users reusing passwords or writing them down.
>
> Con: Password data stores are a weak point - if an intruder gets the
> password store, he gets the motherload.
>
> Con: All parts of password transmission can lead to exposure -
> websites that store passwords locally for ease of use, internal server
> components that transmit in the clear, log files in COTS products that
> store passwords in the clear. With the secret being part of the
> transmission, you're only as strong as your weakest link - it takes
> serious effort to prevent exposure and the requirement is on both the
> user and the system developer.
>
> **Certificates:**
>
> Pro: Doesn't require the transmission of the secret. Proof of private
> key contains no secret information - mitigates all sorts of
> storage/transmission weak points.
>
> Pro: Issued by a trusted party (the CA) which allows for a centralized
> management system for status across multiple applications. If a cert
> goes bad, it can get revoked. Fixing a password breakin must be done
> separately for each system unless a shared ID is used.
>
> Pro: Non-repudiation case is stronger - in most password systems, the
> way the user is initially authenticated prior to account creation is
> pretty weak and the password reset mechanisms can offer another factor
> of plausible deniability. With many forms of certificate issuance,
> it's far harder for a user to say it wasn't them. Caveat - you're
> still only as good as your CA's issuance policies.
>
> Pro: Serves more purposes than just authentication - can provide
> integrity and confidentiality as well.
>
> Con: Still requires a password/pin - almost any private key pair
> storage mechanism is then unlocked with a PIN. SmartCards can have
> tamper protection and lockout capabilities to prevent brute force, but
> that doesn't fix the fact the user wrote his PIN on a sticky note next
> to the computer where the card is docked. Sometimes password issues
> reappear on a smaller scale with PKI.
>
> Con: Complexity of infrastructure - setting up a PKI is no easy task
> and generally so expensive in both deployment and maintenance that it
> can only be used for large/expensive systems.
>
> Con: Certificate Status reporting and updates are not easy - revoking
> a user credential that has become corrupted is onerous due to the size
> and complexity of the infrastructure. Usually, a CA generates a CRL
> that may or may not be provisioned within an OCSP server. Then every
> application should check every login for the CRL or OCSP status. This
> introduces a variety of time delays into the system between the time a
> PKI credential is reported as compromised and the time when the
> systems that rely on that credential actually start denying access.
> The speed of status update can be accelerated - but at a greater
> system complexity cost.